# Disconnect cooker hood controls

Tags: switches

I have a broken plastic part, disabling the button for the light switch on my cooker hood. Now I can fix it, but I've unhooked both the light switch and the hood switch, and I can't find how to connect it again. Forgot to take pictures unfortunately... I've found this circuit online, can anyone help me out how to connect it? Brown thing is the light switch. Can provide better pictures if necessary. Thanks a million in advance!

[image: The mess]

[image: Electric circuit]

Comment: Guess this topic would fit better at the DIY.SE

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't know that existed :)

Comment: Your circuit doesn't seem to bear any resemblance to the wiring you're holding.  In particular, the wires to the lamps aren't yellow.